# momentJs parse Date: Unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Using momentJs I've come across something I don't understand;
let's play around with one particular date, for example `2099-11-11T15:00`

Convert Moment to Date:

```
> moment('2099-11-11T15:00').toDate()  
// => Wed Nov 11 2099 15:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Convert Date to Moment:

```
> var d = new Date('2099-11-11T15:00')  
// => undefined  
> moment(d)  
// => { ... _d: Wed Nov 11 2099 16:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) }
```

We have different *dates*, the first one is wednesday at 15:00 but the second one is wednesday at 16:00. Indeed if we compare them:

```
moment(d).isSame(moment('2099-11-11T15:00'))
// => false
```

---

At first look I thought it was something related with `toDate()` method but it's not; let's type the following:

```
new Date('2099-11-11T15:00').toISOString()
'2099-11-11T15:00:00.000Z'
moment('2099-11-11T15:00').toISOString()
'2099-11-11T14:00:00.000Z'
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- Do not pay attention to the `_d` field.  Underscored fields are internal to moment's API, and may not always be what you expect.  In many functions, it has to be evaluated in combination with *other* internal fields (such as `_offset`) in order to produce a valid output.  Instead, use the various public functions, such as `format`, `toDate`, `.valueOf`, and others.
- Recognize there are many difference between how the `Date` constructor parses strings and how moment's parsing functions work.  Don't expect them to match.
- When a string doesn't contain any time zone information, `moment(...)` will always treat it as local, while `moment.utc(...)` will treat it as UTC.  (Your answer gives a good example of that.)
- When the `Date` constructor is given a string, the format of the string can affect the interpretation significantly.  The actual behavior can vary across implementations, but most current browsers will see the hyphens and the `T` as an indication that the string is in ISO8601 format.  However without any trailing `Z` or offset, the ES5 spec says to interpret those as UTC.  This has changed for ES6, which will treat those cases as *local* time - to better conform with the ISO8601 spec.  Since it's not clear when various environments will start to implement this change, it's prudent to not rely on the `Date` constructor.
- If you wanted the `Date` constructor to interpret your value as *local* time (with ES5), one approach is to use string replacements to remove the `T` and swap the hyphens (`-`) with slashes (`/`).  This works in the majority of environments, though there is no specification around this.  (I've been told it fails in some Safari browsers.)  Really, I would just use Moment's parsing functions, and not rely on the `Date` constructor at all.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I decided to use `moment.utc(...)` instead of `moment()` for every operation, doing so, both times are the same:

```
var d = new Date('2099-11-11T15:00')
var m = moment.utc('2099-11-11T15:00')
m.isSame(moment.utc(d))
// => true
```